What do you call the difference between when a verb expresses an actual state vs a potential state?
Sometimes, the exact same verb can express two different but closely related meanings:

The subject [S] is actually performing an action [V]
The subject [S] is capable of performing an action [V]

To illustrate this with a concrete example, contrast:

Birds that eat grains such as rice are categorized as... [taxonomic classification here]

with

Birds that eat grains such as rice don't actually explode afterwards.

In the first selection, the word "eat" is describing a characteristic of a certain category of birds: they have the ability to eat grains, regardless of whether or not they ever actually get the opportunity. So, a newly hatched fledgeling of whatever species might be a grain-eating bird without ever having actually eaten grains (or anything else).
In the second sentence, it's clear that "eat" refers to something the birds actually do, since there is a reference to the result of said action.
Is there a term for this distinction? It's not "aspect," but maybe something similar?

Another example of the 'potential' usage:


Flying fish have large fins that act like wings to enable them to glide. There is a flying fish swimming in the water underneath our boat.


contrasted with the 'active' usage:


Today there is forecasted to be a severe storm: watch out for flying debris and fish!


Within either context, the intended meaning is clear as being one or the other, but the usage differs for the same construction [i.e., 'flying fish'] between the two examples. The term I'm asking about (if it exists) describes what sets the usage in 1. apart from that in 2.

To satisfy the criteria for using the single-word-requests tag:

Sample sentence: "Just like the difference between 'sits' and 'is sitting' is one of aspect, the difference between 'V' in [some sentence] and [some other sentence] is one of [the word I'm looking for]."
Thesaurus/dictionary searches: Search terms like "potential vs actual action" and "action vs ability grammatical term" didn't turn up anything relevant. It's difficult to research a phenomenon when you don't know its name!
The "best" word: I'm looking for a grammatical term which has at least some official recognition.
What words I've considered, and why they don't work: "aspect" - doesn't fit; "causative vs. inchoative" - not the distinction I'm thinking of (this would be pairs like 'sit' vs. 'set' instead, which is not the same relationship)
Yes, it might also be a compound word or phrase - the 'single' part doesn't really matter.


I think the distinction you've made in "birds that eat" and "birds that eat" is specious.  Neither is actual. Neither is capable.

I'm not sure what you mean: are you saying there's no difference between a flying squirrel that is flying and one that's just perched on a tree branch? (The second could be a "sitting flying squirrel.")

Why is neither 'actual' nor 'capable'?

One note: naming things in programming is, officially, off-topic for this site. We can answer the first part, but it may or may not work as a good term for use in code.

sittable is the ability to be sat [by someone], not the ability to sit.

Flying monkeys are monkeys that [can] fly.

@alphabet Although the question came up in the context of programming, I was asking whether there is a more general (and not domain-specific) term for the concept. I'd already decided to use the name "flying hoglin" since ambiguity isn't actually a problem in context - like Tinfoil Hat says, no one would interpret that other than as a hoglin that can fly. This was just asked out of academic interest :) Also, I didn't come up with that sittable usage, only found it. That's why I mentioned that it wouldn't work in a more general context.

I edited the question to remove all mention of variable names, and of constructions formed by adding the suffix -able. Hopefully it's clearer now what I was actually asking about, but if the consensus is that it's still off topic, I'll delete it since no one has answered yet.

@QuackE.Duck This is on topic and should not be closed.

Please clarify the distinction you're trying to make. Both your first two examples refer to birds that can eat rice; they are in the present tense, but neither refers to birds that are eating rice at the time of the utterance.

I think this question actually lacks clarity but is capable of being clarified.  Both of your examples are statements about something birds (some of them)  actually do: eat grains such as rice.

And they're both statements about things birds (some of them) generally do: eat grains such as rice.   The simple present can make generalizations.

I've seen the following terminology for this situation involving verb voices. Take, for instance,  the verb melt: [active] 'Jill melted the ice cubes.' // [passive] 'The ice cubes were melted.' // [†ergative] 'The chocolate melted almost at once.' (episodic interpretation) // [†middle voice]  'Chocolate melts at 110 degrees F.' (typical †middle usage having to do with permanent properties of entities). see Yang. //// † Though Yang makes this distinction, many grammarians don't use this terminology.

"What do you feed your dog?" The questioner wants to know what you do regularly.  Is  regular behavior "actual" as you see it? Or by "actual" do you mean ongoing at the time of the utterance?

@TimR The present form "do feed" in your example would be 'actual' because it's something the person actually does (regularly, habitually) and not just something they can do.

"Ongoing" isn't relevant, because that would just be an aspect difference

This might be a better question for [linguistics.se]. I presume there are similar words in other languages, so it's not really a question about English.

@EdwinAshworth That "Chocolate melts at 110 degrees F" seems like a nice parallel to the "potential" constructions I was asking about, because it's referring to an intrinsic property of chocolate regardless of the actual temperature.

@Barmar Thank you for the suggestion, but I believe Edwin Ashworth has already provided the answer, with the "middle voice" comment.

I hadn't even considered that, because I had thought of the middle voice as being for constructions that are not explicitly reflexive but where the subject is also affected by the action, such as "They washed and dressed."

@Barmar I'd actually originally planned on asking on ELL, since other languages probably use different forms to express this distinction, so someone there might be able to provide an interesting analysis from that perspective. I asked it here instead because I don't know of any specific examples in other languages where the two forms are separate.

ELL is for questions from learners -- it's for questions that would be too basic for ELU, because any native speaker would not have a problem. It's not for questions where other learners might know the answer because of insight from their native language.

@RosieF I'm not sure how to clarify it further than by the second set of examples I already added, with the "flying fish" sentences.

@Barmar Oh, OK, then I guess it is more of a 'Linguistics' question. I don't have an account there, since it seems more for those with a full-time academic background. Since I'd consider the last example sentence in the melting chocolate comment to be an exact fit, does that make the question on-topic here too?

[correction: A severe storm is forecast for today] There's no concept here, there are just two different ideas after eat. The semantic weight of eat is not different. [to ingest a footstuff]

@Lambie "Forecasted" is listed as an alternative past tense in the dictionary, and sounds more natural (at least to me): "forecast" sounds more formal and 'literary.' What is your opinion on the different usages of "flying fish"? I'm starting to think I should just delete the "eat" example or move it down below the "flying fish" section, since it's the "eat" sentences that seem to be causing all the confusion.

Google ngrams show that 'forecasted' is a rare (and hence quirky) choice.

One of the uses of the simple present tense in English is 'to express habits, general truths, repeated actions or unchanging situations, emotions and wishes' [EF]. Some birds eat grain. // The continuous is used for an instantiation  Some birds are/were eating the berries on the mountain ash. // But Some birds ate berries and some ate grain. is indeterminate between habitual ... and episodic (semelfactive, really).

There is definitely a distinction here but it is not between the actual and the potential. Rather it is between what is (actually) done (from time to time) by a typical, paradigmatic member of a class (but not necessarily by any particular member of it at any particular time), and what is done by some members of the class that are specifically referred to. The difference between the two sentences about birds is not in how eat works in them, but in how birds works.

Today there is forecasted to be a severe storm:= not grammatical in English regardless of forecasted. In flying fish and flying debris there is no change in the semantic core meaning of fly.

@Lambie I will change "forecasted" to "forecast" next edit (Edwin Ashworth convinced me with that first link), but Ngrams would disagree about it being straight-up ungrammatical in that construction: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+forecasted+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 I see quite a few results for "is forecasted to be" and "is forecast to be," from published books.

@jsw29 That is very convincing, and definitely explains the difference between the first set of examples. But, would you say it also fits for the "flying fish" sentences?

It's not clear how birds that eat grain but don't explode has anything more to do with capability of eating than birds that eat grain and are therefore placed in some taxonomic category. Aren't you letting the not exploding and the categorization color your sense of the verb eat?  One has to do with something that has no direct bearing on the bird's life (what people call it) and the other with something that doesn't happen to the bird (it doesn't explode when it eats grain).

It is not the "forecasted to be" that is ungrammatical. It's "There is forecasted to be". That would be like: There is announced to be. or: There is foreseen to be x. Ungrammatical.

@Lambie Oh, I see what you mean. Normally I'd just say something like "They're predicting [xyz] for this afternoon," but I thought that sounded too colloquial for writing.

@All Had Edwin Ashworth's comment about the middle voice been posted as an answer, I would have accepted it, but now the question is closed it can't be. Still, I consider the question [RESOLVED] since that seems like a perfect match. Like I suspected, it is a descriptor with some (but not wide) recognition, and is a general grammatical term, not technical jargon from another field.

Thanks to everyone who answered/commented!

I understand the distinction you are making, but I am not aware of any single word to express the idea that is in common use. If someone else on here knows of such a word, I'll gladly yield. (Maybe it's just not coming to mind.)
If you want to express this idea, you have to use a phrase, like "potential versus actual" -- and then you'd likely have to explain what you meant.
I live in the Philippines and in one of the local languages here, Cebuano, there are actually different verb tenses for these two ideas. For example, "makakaon" means "is able to eat" but "nagkaon" means "is eating". But we do not have different tenses for this in English.

+1 for giving an example of a language which does use two separate forms! I'd guessed that might be the case but wasn't certain.

But we do have modals.

@TimR Yes, when I tried various search terms contrasting "actual" with "potential/ability," all the results showed modal constructions. I'm specifically asking about usages without auxiliaries like "can" and "able to."

@QuackE.Duck  "Birds that eat grains such as rice" is a noun phrase in both instances, and it seems you want to distinguish between "eat" meaning "having as regular diet" and "eat" meaning  "ingest" and assign a name to the nature of that difference in meaning.

@TimR Yes, exactly that! You've put it much more clearly than I did :D

So that when we are referring to an animal's regular diet, we wouldn't say "Carnivores are eating meat" but when referring to ingesting food we would say "Carnivores are eating meat".  I do think aspect is involved in this distinction.

@timr Involved, yes, but not the full story. If someone said, "Carnivores are eating meat", he is referring to an actual action. But if he said, "Carnivores eat meat", he could be referring to an actual action or to a potential action.

You can certainly add words to a sentence to make it clear. "Carnivores generally eat meat" or "Carnivores are able to eat meat", versus, "That carnivore over there is eating meat right now."

@Jay:   If I asked someone  who was looking at a photo to describe it (What is that a picture of?) and all he said was the three words  "Carnivores eat meat", I would think he was a non-native speaker. But if he said "Carnivores are eating meat" I would not think him a non-native speaker.
